# errormsg='the server sent an invalid reply' exitcode=EX_PROTOCOL

Tags: msmtp

I have a php program that uses msmtp. I have two msmtp accounts defined in my local .msmtprc file. One works the other gives me the error message in the title. The account "george" works. The account "information" doesn't. I am at a loss as to why this is...

```
account information
host smtp.office365.com
from information@piccexcellence.com
user information@piccexcellence.com
password XXXXXXXXX
port 587
auth on
tls_nocertcheck
```

```
account george
host smtp.office365.com
from george@piccexcellence.com
user george@piccexcellence.com
password XXXXXXXXX
port 587
auth on
tls_nocertcheck
```

Comment: I've run msmtp -v and msmtp -d. I don't see anything that leads me to what's going on..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do I get "the server sent an invalid reply" for account "information" when account "george" works fine. they are both valid email accounts, and configured the same in .msmtprc